# ConEmu + WSL: Open new console in current tab directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I'm using WSL and ConEmu build 180506. I'm trying to setup a task in ConEmu to use the current directory of the active tab when opening a new console but I cannot get it to work.
What I did is to setup the task {Bash: bash} using the instructions on [this page](https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html)

setting the task command as :

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -C~ -cur_console:pm:/mnt
```

Then following the instruction on [this page](https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#connector-ps1), I added to my .bashrc

```
if [[ -n "${ConEmuPID}" ]]; then
  PS1="$PS1\[\e]9;9;\"\w\"\007\e]9;12\007\]"
fi
```

and finally setup a shortcut using the macro :

```
Shell("new_console", "{bash}", "", "%CD%")
```

But it always open the new console in the default directory (`'/home/[username]'`).

I don't understand what I'm not doing right.
I also noticed that a lot of environment variables [listed here](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuEnvironment.html) are not set. Basically, only $ConEmuPID and $ConEmuBuild seem to be set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use [Old Builds](https://conemu.github.io/en/OldBuild.html)

Comment: I uninstalled ConEmu, downloaded the installer and reinstalled but the problem remains.

Comment: All environment variables has no sense because WSL is Unix subsystem and you can't run Windows binaries there. Does ConEmu show proper CD in Tab title (look for tab templates) or Restart dialog (Win+~)?

Comment: Try macro `Shell("new_console:I", "{bash}", "", "%CD%")`

Comment: ConEmu show proper directory path in the tab title. I tried the macro you posted but I got the following error (sorry it's a screenshot, I could not copy the text from the terminal): https://prnt.sc/ji6jfu
If it might give any relevant info, the "Current Directory" given on the error screen is not the one from where I opened the new tab. It matches the "startup directory for new processes" displayed when I press Win+~ though.

Comment: Regarding the tab templates, I'm not sure I understand. In the "Tab Bar" I see that in console, I have "<%c> %s" which should display "<Console #> Title" but I am not sure where that "Title" is defined. In my case that would correspond to "username@host: current directory". If I switch the console field to "%d" it only display the proper current directory.

Comment: Sorry for the triple comments but I could not edit the previous ones anymore. I tried to change the macro to ```Shell("new_console:I", "{Bash::bash}", "", "%CD%")``` as it is the complete name of the task and instead of the previous error message, I now get http://prntscr.com/ji6wv9 (the first line changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GuiMacro](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#List_of_functions) `Shell` was intended to run certain commands, not tasks.

You think you may try to run macro `Task("{bash}","%CD%")`

Or set your `{bash}` task parameters to `-dir %CD%` and just set hotkey for your task.

Of course both methods require working CD acquisition from shell. Seems like it's OK in your case - `%d` shows proper folder.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I actually have -dir %CD% in the task parameter but that doesn't help neither.
I tried ```Task("{bash}","%CD%")``` but it's not working neither. It always open the home directory for the new console. I'm really stumped as indeed %d shows the correct value!
Is there a way to retrieve that value and store it in an environment variable before opening the new console and then just set in my .bashrc a cd command using that environment variable?

Comment: I got it to work. The issue was that I had ```-C~``` in the task command which was forcing it to go to the home folder, apparently ignoring the task parameter. I removed it and now it works. Sorry, and thank you!

Comment: Actually I restarted ConEmu and it's not working again :-/

Comment: What's happening now: if I am anywhere within my home folder (/home/zupalex/[...]) it opens the new tab in the default startup folder.
If I am anywhere else (e.g. /mnt/d/) it displays en error message "Can't create new console, command execution failed (code 267) the directory name is invalid. [...] Working folder:"\mnt\d"".
Not sure what's happening.

Comment: I think there is an issue in the way the paths are passed between ConEmu and WSL.

Comment: WSL home path can't be mapped to Windows filesystem, so these "invalid" paths can't be processed by ConEmu.

Comment: You removed `-new_console:m:/mnt`?

Comment: I tried to remove it at some point but I put it back. Currently it "kind of" work. It just produces errors if I try to open a new console while being in /mnt root directory or /opt/[...] or any other kind of path which is not either /mnt/[...] (which open the console in the proper location) or /home/user/[...] which open the console in the last known /mnt/[...] path. Is there any workaround to get the WSL "internal" paths working?

Comment: I tried to assign the %CD% value to an environment variable with option ```-eTESTVAR=%CD%``` but then it actually literally assign %CD% to $TESTVAR instead of the value of %CD%

Comment: %CD% is virtual variable processes only in certain places if ConEmu code. But the -e switch is processed by wslbridge. You may try `-eTESTVAR=%ConEmuWorkDir%` instead.

Comment: As I said, certain WSL folders have no representation in Windows filesystem, so ConEmu can't "restart" your shell there.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Just trying to figure out if I could "post process" an invalid path using a environment variable :-)
I'll mark the question solved though as it is solved as best as it can.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Shell("new_console:I", "bash.exe", "", "%CD%")

The readme is actually pretty good: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/master/README.md