# WSL Bash with ZSH integrated in ConEmu - Open Here Issue

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I am using Ubuntu Bash with ZSH installed on WSL, Windows 10.

Command in (ConEmu Task settings):

```
 "%WINDIR%\System32\wsl.exe ~" -cur_console:p
```

Command in (ConEmu Integration settings):

```
-Single -run {Bash::ubuntu} -cur_console:n
```

All other terminals integrated in ConEmu I can open with right click in the current project folder, but Ubuntu Bash opens always in default folder (~).

I tried the settings described here: 
[ConEmu + WSL: Open new console in current tab directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335007/conemu-wsl-open-new-console-in-current-tab-directory)

So, with the command:

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -C~ -cur_console:pm:/mnt
```

It works the same as in my case.

With the correct one:

```
 set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt
```

The terminal opens in current folder and it works, but opens in Bash, no more ZSH.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: And what is the question? Tilda obviously enforses startup in the unix home dir. How to change the shell [described in docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html#wsl-shell).

Comment: With task settings is more clear now, but why it opens the correct path in the Bash terminal instead of ZSH, where I have zsh-autosuggestions, zsh-syntax-highlighting...? How to fix that?

Answer (score 5):

Finally it works with ZSH! My settings:

**Tasks**

```
Bash::ubuntu

-icon "%USERPROFILE%\ubuntu\ubuntu.ico"

"%WINDIR%\System32\wsl.exe" -cur_console:pm:/mnt
```

**Integrations**

```
Bash Here

-Single -run {Bash::ubuntu} -cur_console:n   

%USERPROFILE%\ubuntu\ubuntu.ico
```